# Salt-Stack copy directory from salt master to minion

Tags: saltstack

**Background**: I have been working on setting up a salt-environment, and reached the point where I want to distribute not only files, but also directories. I've found that the most sensible way to do this is to place the directory I want copied in `/srv/salt/path_to_dir` on the master, and then use the [cp.get_dir](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.get_dir) command to distribute it.

**What I have done**: To test the setup and command I created `/srv/salt/tmp/foo` and placed two files in it. Then when I run the command `salt minion_name cp.get_dir salt://tmp/foo /tmp/foo` on the master there is one line of output that reads exactly `minion_name:`. Somewhat strange that there is no output except the minion name, even error, but ok, I go to check the minion to see if anything has happened.

On the minion it has not appeared in `/tmp/`, and there is no new content in `/etc/salt/` or `/var/cache/salt/` either. I checked in `/var/log/salt/minion`, but there is nothing except my hour old attempts at figuring out why I couldn't use `file.copy` with recursion set to true for distributing files.

**My question(s)**: Is there anything obvious that I have done wrong? According to the documentation I found what I have done should work. There doesn't seem to be any error output either. Should I try using a different command or approach to distribute folders with content from the master through salt instead?

**Additional information**: Both the master and all the minions are Debian-systems. The installed versions of salt are `salt 2014.1.3 (Hydrogen)` on the master and `salt-minion 0.17.5` and `salt-minion 2015.5.3` on the minions I have tried this approach with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can do this using modules, I tried the same ones you did and had the same results, so possibly a bug, but if you want to set up an sls state you can use the file.recurse functionality, it looks like this:

as reference I'm using:

- `/srv/salt/test1/init.sls` as my sls file,
- inside `test1` is the *src* directory `testdir`
- our *target* on the machine we want to copy to is `/test`

**`init.sls`**

```
/test:
 file.recurse:
  - source: salt://test1/testdir
  - include_empty: True
```

from that point you can

```
salt '<targetmachine>' state.sls test1
```

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to hear that it's not just something I messed up, and also your solution works nicely =) There is a slight typo though, I guess it was supposed to be '<targetmachine>' and not '<targetmachine>/, but I could not suggest an edit of only one char, so I'm just putting it down here.

Comment: haha, Yeah, Definitely a typo, Fixed. Glad that it worked out for you. Hopefully whatever is wrong with the cp module will get fixed in the near future.